# JQuery Infinite Scroll loads multiple identical $(document).ready events, and fires them multiple times

Tags: jquery, .net, document-ready, infinite-scroll

I'm new to jquery and am hoping this is a simple issue, but am running out of ideas.

I am working with .net and have a page that includes a few custom jquery functions like the below for following a user. This works perfectly fine when the page first loads.

The issue comes with infinite scrolling, where I am posting to another page and appending the results. If I append the results without re-including the below function on that posted page, it will never fire the event when I click the newly appended links. But if I do include this exact same snippet again, it works correctly. EXCEPT that all previous links on the page now fire an extra time.

So if i scroll down through 5 pages of data and then click on the first link on the page, it now fires 6 times!! The newest one I added only fires once.

I see some stuff about debouncing and throttling, but this seems even more simplistic than that - isn't there a way to only load this function once and have it work for the appended data?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('a.FollowJQ').click(function () {

     var username = $(this).attr('data');

     $.post('/jquery/follow.aspx',{ user: username },

       function (data) {

          if (!data.error) {

           if (data.server == 'SendToLoginPage') { window.location = "/login.aspx" }

              else { $('a.FollowJQ:[data=' + username + ']').html(data.server); }  }

                    else { $('a.FollowJQ:[data=' + username + ']').html(data.server); }

                        }, 'json');
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.click()`, you need to use `.on()` (jQ 1.7 onward) to delegate to an ancestor element as the listener. Bind once and then any '`a.FollowJQ`' can execute the function.

```
$('#wrapper').on("click", "a.FollowJQ", function() { ..the function.. });
```

If using jQuery 1.6.x, .delegate() will do the same:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate("a.FollowJQ", "click", function() { ..the function.. });
```

In the samples, `"#wrapper"` is any ancestor element of `"a.FollowJQ"` elements that is not expected to be destroyed by any other DOM manipulation. The closest common ancestor will have the best performance.

Comment: Hi Greg,Thanks for the response. This makes sense but I'm having trouble implementing it. I'm not clear if this will only exist once on the original page or if it still needs to be added on the posted to page? Ie, will the original page still have the $('a.FollowJQ').click(function and then only the posted to page has the $('#FollowWrapper').on("click", "a.FollowJQ", function ? Or are you saying i only need to add this to the original page and the posted pages will find it?  Many thanks for your help! I'm happy to hear this is a common need:)

Comment: This completely replaces the original .click() binding. The above is called once on the "main" page only, with "#wrapper" being replaced by any ancestor element that will not be destroyed when posted pages are loaded. It could even be "body" if you're desperate, but better to go deeper if possible. So "#wrapper" is actually the listener; when you click any a.FollowJQ, even ones added later, #wrapper can "hear" the click. The term "ancestor" means that Your a.FollowJQ need to be children, grandchildren, great-grand-children (etc) of #wrapper.

Comment: Thanks so much Greg! This was what I was missing. Was able to get it all working now with a single placement in my basepage. Perfect! Thanks so much for your help and great explanation!

Comment: Double thumbs-up to finger-pistol points and tongue-clacking "click click" sound effects (No problem!)